# Using nokogiri to parse XML and create records with multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, activerecord, nokogiri

Feels like I'm missing something pretty obvious here but can't see it.

I have an XML file and are using the Nokogiri gem.

The XML looks like this (imagine if you will an infinite amount of 'variants'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<products> 
    <variant> 
        <sku type="string">123abc</sku>
        <inventory-quantity type="integer">68</inventory-quantity> 
    </variant> 
    <variant> 
        <sku type="string">321cba</sku>
        <inventory-quantity type="integer">22</inventory-quantity> 
    </variant>
</products>
```

I want to loop over the variants and create a corresponding record for each that contains the 'sku' and 'inventory-quantity' attributes.

This is what I've got so far, but instead of creating individual records, in the above case it creates two records and inserts the complete array or NodeSet that Nokogiri returns into each records attribute. So this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/new.xml")) 

variant = doc.xpath("//variant")

variant.each do |product| 

  sku = product.xpath("//sku").text
  quan = product.xpath("//inventory-quantity").text

  Productmapping.create(:sku => sku, :product_quantity => quan)

end
```

creates this...

```
sku              inventory-quantity

123abc321cba     6822
123abc321cba     6822
```

Where I actually want:

```
sku              inventory-quantity

123ab            68
321cba           22
```

It looks like it's because the xpath locator returns all occurrences into an array and I'm calling that array and inserting it for each record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is simple - instead of:

```
sku = product.xpath("//sku").text
quan = product.xpath("//inventory-quantity").text
```

just use:

```
sku = product.xpath("sku").text
quan = product.xpath("inventory-quantity").text
```

It's because `//sku` selects all the sku descendants of the document root.

Comment: Simple indeed, just what I'd hoped (and missed). Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. THANK YOU. Jesus, stuck on this forever!

Answer (score 1):

Smth like:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/new.xml"))  

variant = doc.xpath("//variant")

sku, quan = nil, nil
variant.each do |product| 


  product.children.each do |child|
      case child.name
       when 'sku'  
          sku = child.text
       when 'inventory-quantity'
          quan = child.text
       end
    end

  Productmapping.create(:sku => sku, :product_quantity => quan)

end
```

Or more magic and not beautiful but compact way:

```
sku = product.children[1].text
quan = product.children[3].text
```

Comment: It's inefficient to loop over all children, checking the name. And as you mention, indexing by position is 'not beautiful'. Better to specify directly, e.g. `product.at('sku').text`